# Create a column by filtering and dividing another column with a specific number to get the reminder in R

Tags: r

Would like to add a column which takes the week number i.e. 01,02,06...32 and gives the reminder when divided by 13 (one quarter contains 13 weeks)

**df**

```
Year    Quarter  Weeks
2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W01
2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W02
2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W06
2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W011
2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W013
2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W014
2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W025
2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W032
```

So the output should be as shown below:

```
Year    Quarter  Weeks  Weeks.rltv
2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W01     1
2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W02     2
2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W06     6
2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W011    11
2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W013    13
2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W014    2
2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W025    12
2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W032    6
```

Comment: There is a discrepancy in your output - week 1 and week 13 both are assigned `1` in the column `Weeks.rltv`

Comment: Thanks Sumedh, have corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather that we can ignore the year and that the weeks within each quarter should be numbered from 1 to 13 (and not 0 to 12) so we must subtract 1 from the weeks, take the remainder and add one.  No packages are used:

```
transform(DF, weeks.rltv = (as.numeric(sub(".*W", "", Weeks)) - 1) %% 13 + 1)
```

giving:

```
     Year Quarter     Weeks weeks.rltv
1 2014-FY 2014-Q1  2014-W01          1
2 2014-FY 2014-Q1  2014-W02          2
3 2014-FY 2014-Q1  2014-W06          6
4 2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W011         11
5 2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W013         13
6 2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W014          1
7 2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W025         12
8 2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W032          6
```

**Note:** The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "Year    Quarter  Weeks
2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W01
2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W02
2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W06
2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W011
2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W013
2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W014
2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W025
2014-FY 2014-Q1 2014-W032"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```